# how to specify async callback function as reply in nock?

Tags: typescript, async-await, jestjs, nock

I have a nock interceptor that intercepts calls from an async function (Which returns a promise)

```
public async backendRes(): Promise<container> {
  get some data from abckend 
  return new container(stat, body, header);
}
```

im calling it using nock like this:

```
nock()
  .get('/goodey')
  .reply(async function () {
    let abc = await global.MyClass.backendRes();
    return [abc.getStatus(), abc.getBody(),
      abc.getHeader()];
  });
```

But this doesnt work - somehow the reply within the nock is wrong. I am not sure how to fix it. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The current [nock documentation](https://github.com/nock/nock#specifying-replies) doesn't mention that `reply()` supports `async` / Promise-returning functions, but only a callback argument or node.js streams.

According to that you could use the callback mechanism instead, the callback is provided as a third argument:

```
nock()
  .get('/goodey')
  .reply(async function (uri, requestBody, cb) {
    let abc = await global.MyClass.backendRes();
    cb(null, [abc.getStatus(), abc.getBody(),
      abc.getHeader()];
    return;
  });
```